# Count length of each class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code also in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/Pdwzv/).

**HTML**

```
    <span class="myName">John Smith</span>
    <span class="myName">John Smith</span>
    <span class="myName">John Smith</span>
    <span class="myName">John Smith</span>
    <span class="myName">John Smith</span>
    <span class="myName">John Smith</span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    $('.myName').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).html().split(' '),
            len = text.length,
            test = $(this).val().length,
            result = []; 
        console.log('outside: ' + test);
        for( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
            result[i] = '<span class="name-'+[i]+'" >' + text[i] + '</span>';
            console.log('inside: ' + test);
        }
        $(this).html(result.join(' '));
        console.log('after: ' + test);
    });
```

It adds a span to each word in the myName div.
I want to count the Charecters in each div so that if it is a long name I can cut the first name down to J Smith for example.

But if you look at the console log I have tried to count the length in three different places and it always comes back as 0?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.val()` function works only for inputs (you would know that if you read the manual http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: "I have tried to count the length in three different places" -- you have counted it once and then output the same result 3 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zerkms is right. you want to change this:

```
test = $(this).val().length,
```

to this:

```
test = $(this).text().length,
```